# Why does h2xs generate module name with trailing colons?

Tags: perl

I ran h2xs to start a new Perl module.  It creates the main module and Makefile.PL with a package name ending with double colons.  For example, in My/Module.pm:

```
package My::Module::
```

and in Makefile.PL:

```
WriteMakefile(
    NAME   => 'My::Module::',
    ...
);
```

As a consequence, the tiny script

```
perl -Ipath/to/my/module -MMy::Module -e 'print $My::Module::VERSION, "\n"'
```

prints nothing.

When I change the package name to 'My::Module' without the trailing colons, that script will print the version number.

Why does h2xs append the '::' to the main package name by default?  I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Perl 5.18.2

Comment: It would help to know the exact `h2xs` command line that you ran. It's never done that for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: trailing double colon signals that we are dealing with package name.

Example from [perlmonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=986250) :

```
use 5.010;

{
   package Foo;
   sub new { bless [] }
   sub Bar { 'Quux' }
}
{
   package Foo::Bar;
   sub new { bless [] }
}
{
   package Quux;
   sub new { bless [] }
}

my $object1 = Foo::Bar::->new;
say ref $object1;   # says "Foo::Bar"

my $object2 = Foo::Bar->new;
say ref $object2;   # says "Quux"
```